# Condição if dentro da função map

Tags: javascript

Como posso colocar uma condição `if` em minha função para ela não retornar um valor `undefined`?

Essa é minha função:

```
keys.map(key => ({ key, value: data[key] }))
```

Ela retorna isso:

```js
[ { key: 'a', value: 2 },
  { key: 'b', value: 2 },
  { key: 'c', value: 2 },
  { key: 'd', value: undefined },
  { key: 'e', value: undefined },
  { key: 'f', value: 2 } ]
```

Tentei de alguns jeitos mas sem sucesso.

Uma das minhas tentativas:

```
keys.map(key => (if(data[key]!=undefined) {{key, value: data[key]}}))
```

Comment: Se você quer apenas eliminar os valores `undefined` você não precisa de um `map`, mas sim de um `filter`. O `map` define uma relação 1:1 e sempre retorna uma saída para cada entrada.

Comment: Para ultrapassar  questões relacionados com **Arrays** e **Objectos** te recomendo vivamente a usar [https://underscorejs.org](underscorejs) - _uma biblioteca JavaScript que fornece uma gama funções auxiliares de programação_ . Por exemplo, nesse caso era só fazer isso:  `_.without(keys, undefined)` e retorna uma copia do array sem o _undefined_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você **não pode remover itens diretamente pelo [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, tendo em vista que, por definição, esse método retorna um array com o mesmo comprimento do array inicial, fazendo apenas modificações em seus valores.

Nesse caso, você teria que usar o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) após o `map` para remover os elementos indesejados da lista. Algo assim:

```js
const data = {
  a: 2,
  b: 2,
  c: 2,
  d: undefined,
  e: undefined,
  f: 2
}

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

const final = keys
  // Esse `map` faz exatamente a mesma coisa que a sua pergunta:
  .map((key) => ({ key, value: data[key] }))
  // Esse `filter` irá manter no array somente valores que
  // sejam diferentes (`!==`) de `undefined`.
  .filter((obj) => obj.value !== undefined)

console.log(final)
```

Perceba no trecho de código acima que os objetos cuja propriedade `value` era igual a `undefined` foram removidos do array.